# How to load the HTML templates from data base in spring thymeleaf 3.?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How to load my string content of the HTML template from DB in spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE and THYMELEAF3.0.

```
Context context = new Context(); 
context.setVariable("comments", comments); 
templateEngine.process("singup-request-user-template", context);//HERE I NEED TO PASS THE DB LOADING CONTENT
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a Thymeleaf template from DB in Thymeleaf 3.0.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598674/how-to-read-a-thymeleaf-template-from-db-in-thymeleaf-3-0-5)

Comment: yes you are correct but i need 3.0.5 but ThymeleafDatabaseResourceResolver is not working as i expect

Comment: can you please then clarify, what do you expect as the result and what do you get using `ThymeleafDatabaseResourceResolver`

Comment: I have the Thyme-leaf HTML templates are there in MS SQL Server database.And i want those while sending the email.

Comment: Context context = new Context();
context.setVariable("comments", comments); 
templateEngine.process("singup-request-user-template", context);//HERE I NEED TO PASS THE DB LOADING CONTENT

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `ThymeleafDatabaseResourceResolver` the other option would be to fetch your template manually in java code, and then process it:

```
String databaseTemplate = ...fetch template from db...
Context context = new Context(Locale.ENGLISH);
...set variables for context....
String processedTemplate = templateEngine.process(databaseTemplate, context);
```

You should also manually create template engine:

```
SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(new SpringResourceTemplateResolver());
templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(new StringTemplateResolver());
templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(new FileTemplateResolver());
```

This would work if your database contains either path to the template file or template content itself.
However if you are sure that your database always holds a path to file, then you can just autowire standard `TemplateEnging` configured by `spring-boot`.

Also you might want to take a look at `ITemplateResolver` interface and its implementations, in case your templates are located somewhere else.

Comment: let me try from my machine.Thanks for your time @Ruslan

Comment: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/testing the email.html]")

Comment: I got the above exception from my machine if use the below code.

Comment: Optional<Template> template = templateRepository.findById(1l);

  if (template.isPresent()) {
   return templateEngine.process(template.get().getContent(), context);
  } else {
   return null;
  }

Comment: @anilkumarreddy from what I see in this exception, in database you are storing not a template, but a path to a template file(e.g. `templates/testing the email.html`), is that right?

Comment: Yes i am calling database fetch the string content and pass to the templateEngine.process method.

Comment: @anilkumarreddy when you are saying template content it usually means the template itself, not a path to the file with template, however from your exception message I see that you are actually passing path to the file with template. I updated the code so you can handle both type of templates.

Comment: Does someone have any example doing this in GitHub??